# Using a distance matrix to store distances between points and finding closest neighbor

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, distance

I need help with an assignment. I generated two parallel arrays to hold the position of 8 points(one holds x coordinates, one holds y coordinates). The user then inputs the coordinates of these points. I have gotten my code working perfectly fine up to this point but this is where I need help:

I must calculate the distance between each pair of points and then store the distances in a 2d array. After doing this I have to print the distance array row by row.

After doing this I must then next use the distance matrix(the 2d array) to find the nearest neighbor of each point.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if I need to elaborate on anything.

Here is my current code, I do not know where to go from here.

```
double distance(double x1,double y1,double x2 ,double y2)
{
double distance;

distance = sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));

return distance;
}

int main()
{
double xPoint[6];
double yPoint[6];
double matrix[6][6];

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the x coordinate for position " << i << ": " << endl;
    cin >> xPoint[i];
    cout << "Enter the y coordinate for position " << i << ": " << endl;
    cin >> yPoint[i];
}

for(int x =0; x<6; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<6; y++)
    {
        matrix[x][y] = distance()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

/*double distance(double x1,double y1,double x2 ,double y2)
 {
double x;

x= sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));

return x;
 }
*/
int main()
 {
double xPoint[6];
 double yPoint[6];
// double matrix[6][6];

 for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
cout << "Enter the x coordinate for position " << i << ": " << endl;
cin >> xPoint[i];
cout << "Enter the y coordinate for position " << i << ": " << endl;
cin >> yPoint[i];
 }

  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
  // for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
double X=sqrt(pow(xPoint[i+1]-xPoint[i],2)+pow(yPoint[i+1]-yPoint[i],2));

 cout<<X<<"    ";
 cout<<endl;
 // }
 }
 }
```

do you want like this? I may not completely understand your problem